# Unable to boot Android in Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04, android-source, vmware-workstation

I am trying to build AOSP in Ubuntu 14.04LTS VM (Vmware workstation instance). I successfully checked out the master branch and start building. Build is successful however I am unable to boot AOSP using the emulator. When I start the emulator after the build, it opens with an empty screen, nothing happens. I also downloaded, extracted and executed the proprietary binaries but it does not change the result. Any advice on this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Environment**

First of all, make sure you set your environment with the changes to ~/.bashrc that Android recommends, including:

```
export USE_CCACHE=1 ccache -M 10G
```

Follow the steps for downloading the Android source, if you haven't already done so.
Then set up some functions for the environment:

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
```

You now should actually execute one of those functions to get the paths set correctly (as Pingzhong Li pointed out, this is not mentioned in the Android build instructions!):

```
$ set_stuff_for_environment
```

**First build**

Start building! For instance:

```
$ lunch full-eng $ make -j4
```

(Here, 4 threads is ideal for my machine. Change as you see fit.)
When the build finishes, simply launch the emulator:

```
$ emulator
```

**Subsequent builds**

To get the system.img to rebuild, you need to remove the following files/directories:

> out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING/
>
> out/target/product/generic/system.img

Then simply repeat:

```
$ make -j4 $ emulator
```

Comment: ok I followed the build steps outlined in the source.android.com. Build is successfully generated but my emulator starts with no OS booted. What is causing this ? Any info, log vs that I can find to check ?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching emulator from the command line - you will receive output there. Here's the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html), but generally it will be something like this command:

`path/to/android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd [AVD_NAME]`

Please add the output to the question as an edit.

If you get a response like the following I would expect your have updated you emulator version to `25.3.1` recently?

```
[139762647099200]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file or directory
```

You can fix this by launching the emulator with the following command (assuming the system libs e.g. Qt are compatible - most likely not):

`path/to/android/sdk/tools/emulator -use-system-libs -avd [AVD_NAME]`

Or by manually downgrading from version `25.3.1` to `25.2.3` of the SDK tools.